# When did police uniforms change in New York from the British design?

Tags: uniform, police, law-enforcement

The US law enforcement system (to the best of my knowledge) has followed a system similar to the UK system. The New York Police Department (NYPD) has used uniforms that mimicked their British counterparts, having greatcoats, Custodian helmets, all in a dark blue/black:

[image: 19th century NYPD officer]

*New York police officer in 1899*

At some point in the next 50 years after the above photograph was taken, uniforms evolved into either a black or white shirt, peaked cap and black trousers:
[image: Modern NYPD officers]
*Modern NYPD officers, Courtesy of Flickr*

At what point was there this transition in uniforms and which was the first?

Secondary question - Where did this new uniform style come from? Last time I checked, no European police force used this style of uniform until the 1950s, so it could surely be assumed that this uniform style did not come from Europe.

Comment: Ahh, Wikipedia strikes again. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_uniforms_in_the_United_States

Comment: Not really answerable, since New York City is not the US.  Just about every jurisdiction had and has its own uniform.  Hereabouts, I'm most likely to encounter these gray with black decoration uniforms, and Smokey-the-Bear hats: https://www.reviewjournal.com/local/local-nevada/nevada-highway-patrol-finishes-transition-to-gray-uniforms-1562954/  Or the county sheriffs, who wear a brown uniform.  You'd have to look up the history of the particular place you're interested in.

Comment: Chesterfield County VA police changed from its forest green uniform, worn since the 1920's, to all black in 2019.  The county Sherriff's made the change from brown to dark blue in 2016.  Virginia law used to, but no longer, specified uniform colors for sherriff's and police departments uniforms and even vehicle colors.

Comment: Is there any instance of a British policeman wearing a uniform close to the design in that first, New York, 1899 photo?